# Google search autocomplete address api - search address only particular city

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I am using google search address autocomplete api in my website. 
I want to search only the addresses for a particular city, like choose Mumbai city
Below code is used to search only the country India

```
<input type="text" id="address">

<script type="text/javascript">
  var input = document.getElementById('address');
  var options = {componentRestrictions: {country:'ind'}};
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope Its work proper for you... Thanks..

```
"https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/q8XS6/"
```